# I am using apache-tika for text extraction . I am getting the following error while extracting text from a file

Tags: apache-tika

Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/drew/imaging/jpeg/JpegProcessingException

Comment: Add the missing jars to your classpath? And/or get a tool like Apache Maven or Gradle to handle the dependencies for you?

Comment: I have solved this error. Actually i was missing metedata_extractor jar, thus added dependency for that in my project. Now, it's working fine